# How to use vscode server as git difftool

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to set up vscode as a `git` `difftool` like in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-diff-tool.

However, I can't seem to get it to work, because I use remote ssh. So I'm not trying to run vscode on the remote machine, but rather I want to use the **vscode server** to send it to my local machine.

How do I have to set up the git config for that?

Answer (score 1):

i think  u can write this via ssh:

> `git config --global diff.tool vscode`
>
> `git config --global difftool.vscode.cmd " cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"`

Comment: I recommend adding `--reuse-window` to the command so it doesn't open a new window for each file.